# Oracle SQL query returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

After executing a block of queries, there is no data showing up in the SQL Developer's result tab, it is since a few days lately, it was perfectly fine before then. It shows in the below screenshot, the queries are errorless and executes perfectly, and even the data column names are showing up, but not the data, anyone have an idea about this? please help!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the 'WHERE' filter to check if there is still data in your tables.